# Make a half row break <br>

Tags: html, css

If i want to remove the space between rows of those two element's how would i do that. Example:

[Example 1 http://pokit.org/get/img/6be8921b47ff746c1bf297cf87ab0950.jpg](http://pokit.org/get/img/6be8921b47ff746c1bf297cf87ab0950.jpg)

If i remove the `<br>` it would be like this then this is how it looks like:

[Example 2 http://pokit.org/get/img/1924cb8a9b344bb4f4eda1a98760fd3e.jpg](http://pokit.org/get/img/1924cb8a9b344bb4f4eda1a98760fd3e.jpg)

The rows are to close one to other. I wonder how can i make like  half  of the `<br>` tag . If you understand my question ?

The space between two rows should be less than in example 1. but higher then in example 2.

This is code used

```
    <span class="tekst">Sie besuchten Düsseldorf als:</span><br>
    <select name="posjeta" class="optiontekst">
        <option>- bitte wählen -</option>
        <option>Geschäftsreisende</option>
        <option>Privatperson</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
```

And the class tekst

```
.tekst{
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
    color: #2980b9;
    }
```

I know i didn't explained well but i tried my best.

Comment: While you're at it, might as well make the `<span class="tekst">` a label instead: `<label for="posjeta" class="tekst"></label>` and `<select name="posjeta" class="optiontekst" id="posjeta">` (a unique `id` attribute on your select and a matching unique `for` attribute on your label)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `<br>` tag just adds in a standard line break to the document. You can adjust the size of the `<br>` element in your CSS:

```
  br {
    line-height: 10px;
 }
```

Or you can use a trick with `<hr>`; setting the height and making it invisible

```
<hr style="height:10px; visibility:hidden;" />
```

Comment: I like what you did with `<hr>`, now I don't have to change all my line breaks :)

Comment: Awesome Possum!!

Comment: Not a half break.  this only works if a fll break happens to be 20.

Comment: @Mr.Beeblebrox The "10" is an example; the point is that it is entirely configurable to whatever spacing you want.

Answer (score 12):

If you only want to do it in one place, you can apply line-height directly to the 
 element as: `<br style="line-height: 10px" />`

Comment: I like this answer too - did not know you could do that with the ,<bruh/> tag

Answer (score 8):

**This worked for me:-**

```
<p style="margin:10px;"></p>
```

Comment: Note one should use a value of `.5em` for `half of the <br> tag` as OP mentioned.

Comment: This is good as it works on safari too.

Answer (score 6):

A few options:

- add a `margin-bottom` or `padding-bottom` to the element on top
- add a `margin-top` to the select

There are probably many other possibilities to achieve this.

Comment: yes - or even a simple 'blank' block level div between would also work -  
<div style="margin-bottom:0.5em;"></div> Hopefully the user already has defined divs and can use those already in use.

Answer (score 3):

You can use margins :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/nzwE5/)**

*HTML :*

```
 <span class="tekst">Sie besuchten Düsseldorf als:</span>
<select name="posjeta" class="optiontekst">
    <option>- bitte wählen -</option>
    <option>Geschäftsreisende</option>
    <option>Privatperson</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
```

*CSS :*

```
.tekst {
    font-family:'Bree Serif', serif;
    color: #2980b9;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:10px;   /* adapt the margin value to the desire space between span and select box */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add a margin-bottom span element

OR

add a margin-top to the select element

For example:

```
tekst {
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

OR

```
optiontekst {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML :**

```
<span class="tekst">Sie besuchten Düsseldorf als:</span>
    <select name="posjeta" class="optiontekst">
        <option>- bitte wählen -</option>
        <option>Geschäftsreisende</option>
        <option>Privatperson</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
```

**CSS :**

```
.tekst{
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
    color: #2980b9;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

Try this code it will work for you.