# How to make a smaller newline?

Tags: html, css

I have been searching all over for a way to make my `<br>` tag display less whitespace between the two lines it is separating.

I have some text with a text-input and beneath that I want to have an image. The `<br>` tag makes too large of a gap, but without the `<br>` tag the image appears on the line with the text. Note that the `<br>` makes the perfect size gap for the rest of the elements in the `div`.

```
 <div>
   ...<!--Some other text and text inputs-->
   <br>Some stuff:&nbsp;<input type="text">
   <br><!--I need this br to be a smaller gap-->
   <img id="plus" src="plus.png" height="30px" width="30px">
 </div>
```

## So my question is how do I make that distance smaller?

[image: The issue]

---

**What I've tried**

Now I have tried a *lot* of things! Some of these include editing the br in CSS like

```
br {
 display: block;
 margin: 1px 0;
 line-height:1px;
 content: " ";
}
```

or a combination of those attributes, but no matter which ones I use the minimum height it gets the space down to is the same as the default `<br>`. It works well for increasing the `<br>` space, though.<sup>[src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409649/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-br)</sup>

I tried putting the `<br>` tag inside of a `<div>`, but when that `<div>` is inside my other `<div>`, it immediately makes a gap that is the same height as a default `<br>` (even if I don't have a `<br>` inside my new `<div>`). Setting the line-height of the new `<div>` doesn't affect this either.<sup>[src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409649/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-br)</sup>

```
<div style="line-height:0px;">
  <br>
</div>
```

I tried using a `<hr>` with the visibility: hidden, but that made the gap larger than the `<br>`.<sup>[src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467036/make-a-half-row-break-br)</sup>

I tried many, many, different variations of putting `<div>`s within `<div>`s and setting the line-height, but no matter what I get to it ends up not affecting the space between the text-area and the image without messing up everything else in the original `<div>`.

Comment: Don't use a br tag. Put your text in span's, div's or p's.

You can then properly set the css you're trying to apply.

Comment: Use `margin/padding` instead. You can't set height etc. to `<br> `. The correct one tag is `label` around the text (you can include input into label too).

Comment: @StevenStark: better than span/div/p is `label` in this case.

Comment: @panther How so? labels are for form elements, which are not present. span would be my preference here.

Comment: @panther Having a single input doesn't justify using a label here. 

Trying to use a label will apply CSS rules that aren't desired by the OP. It could work, yes, but it's be more work.

Comment: @StevenStark: Ah, you're right. I saw inputs after both `br`s... my fault. deleted my prev comment

Comment: Add `* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}` and go on from there.

Comment: When I add in a `<p>` or a `<div>` instead of a `<br>` it makes an even larger gap in between the text-area and the image? And I can't mess with the outermost `<div>` because the line spacing is correct for everything else in it, and I use `<br>`s earlier in it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<p>` html elements instead of breaks.

```
<p>some stuff</p>    
<p>some other stuff</p>
```

**EDIT**: With CSS:

```
p {line-height:5px;}
```

Comment: Why the minus one?

Comment: Minus for a bad answer? It won't work. You should try it before first.

Comment: Still not good solution. Try to expand the text into two lines (longer label to input). Forget this task, I won't comment it more.

Comment: I think because the paragraphs are floating left and are on the right side of the screen (as my div was), when I put the image and the text in two separate paragraphs it creates a large gap in between them. See image (colorized for effect): https://snag.gy/cIBGz5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Remove **br** tag, here you can do whatever you want to do with image.

```
#plus{
 //use css properties to play with image
}
```

Comment: What can I edit about the image that will make it squish closer to the text above it?

Comment: #plus{
margin-top:1%;
}

Comment: Ah, works for increasing the distance between the img and the text, but anything lower than 1% (e.g. 0 or a negative number) just sets the distance to the default amount of space a `<br>` creates.