# How to add half a line break to shiny app?

Tags: html, r, shiny, line-breaks

I have a shiny app, and I want to add a small line break in between 2 objects--is it possible to specify that you want `br()` to be half it's regular size? I know if I wanted it to be double the size, I'd do `br()`, `br()`, but I don't know how to make it smaller.

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467036/make-a-half-row-break-br/24467127) answer your question?  `<br style="line-height: 10px" />`

Comment: With shiny syntax: `shiny::tags$br(style="line-height: 10px")`. Remember shiny just generates HTML. If you want to style that HTML, use CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `br()` you can add a margin to the bottom of the element of any size.

```R
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  p("Line 1"),
  br(),
  p("Line 2", style = "margin-bottom: 0px;"),
  p("Line 3", style = "margin-bottom: -10px;"),
  p("Line 4")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```